# Mutt integration with procmail

Tags: email, procmail, mutt

I use following `procmailrc` with fetchmail:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin 
VERBOSE=off  
LOGFILE=$HOME/.procmaillog 
DEFAULT=$HOME/mail/
MAILDIR=$HOME/mail/
# Recipes below this comment:

:0:
* ^(To|From):.*foo@mail.ru
QObject/

:0:
* ^(To|From|Reply-To):.*bar@googlegroups.com
BlackFlame/
```

So, It generates mailbox(with cur,tmp,new) folder `~/mail` and `~/mail/QObject`.
Now, I use mutt and expect it to show me all my messages, and two separated folders.
But I see only default mail box. Here is my muttrc:

```
set realname = "illusionoflife"
set from = "illusion.of.life92@gmail.com"
set use_from = yes
set envelope_from ="yes"

# Use a signature
set signature="~/.signature"

# Use msmtp rather than sendmail. Check that 
# the path is correct for your system:
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"   

# If not set in ~/.bashrc:
set spoolfile = "$HOME/mail"

#======================================================#
# Folders
set folder="$HOME/mail"      # Local mailboxes stored here
set record="+sent"           # Where to store sent messages
set postponed="+postponed"   # Where to store draft messages
set mbox_type=mbox           # Mailbox type
set move=no                  # Don't move mail from spool

#======================================================#
# Watch these mailboxes for new mail, useful only if 
# Procmail or Maildrop is used to sort mail.
mailboxes ! +slrn +fetchmail +mutt
set sort_browser=alpha    # Sort mailboxes by alpha(bet)
```

I feel I do not fully understand unix mail philosophy, but where exactly I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you set your mailbox type to mbox while you're using maildir.

I would look through your system's /etc/Muttrc (or possibly muttrc--it's often better if you mention what system you're using, as various Linux distributions and other Unix and Unixlike systems have their own idiosyncracies).and see what it gives as default--it will often give choices too.

In my own .muttrc I don't use a spoolfile--usually, that's /var/mail/ by default.

I have a mutt page at http://srobb.net/mutt.html that might be useful for setup, though it doesn't say much about using Maildir format.

Anyway, that would be the first thing I'd check, changing the muttrc to Maildir from mbox..  Secondly, when in mutt, don't you have the option to hit c to change directory, and if you hit it a few times, doesn't it eventually show your entire $HOME directory?